# How to pass environment to start-stop-daemon based nginx init script

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, start-stop-daemon

I am using Nginx with Passenger to serve a Rails app. I have hit a strange problem where NginX is not reading the environment variables that the app needs when started normally by the init script. I am using this script: https://github.com/JasonGiedymin/nginx-init-ubuntu/blob/master/nginx 
When NginX starts via the script the environment variables are not set.
If I stop the server, and then restart it manually by doing:

```
-E /opt/nginx/sbin/nginx
```

then the environment variables are set.
My question is how do I get the init script to do this as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the variables to the script

`export VAR='/blah'`

Comment: This won't work because the only reference I have for the variable is the variable itself (I don't want to hard code values in an init script), and they are not being passed in. So I would have to do export VAR=$VAR The environment variables are being set in /etc/environment